# Accessing IPI installation on an isolated network through a proxy

Tags: openshift, haproxy

I'm looking for some help configuring haproxy on a gateway vm to allow me to access an openshift installation on an isolated network.

Here is the layout:
192.168.1.x subnet - main network
10.0.0.x subnet - isolated network
router/gateway system is on 192.168.1.50 with a second nic on 10.0.0.1 and acts as router/dhcp/dns for isolated network
IPI installation uses 10.0.0.50 for *.apps and 10.0.0.51 for api.
a vm on the isolated network accesses openshift fine
main network dns points *.apps to 192.168.1.50 which is running haproxy
firewall rules in place for http and https
system on the main network gets to the haproxy (confirmed by looking at the ssl cert)
traffic does not proxy to *.apps

Error in browser is 503 service unavailable - No server is available to handle this request.

Here is my haproxy config:

```
global
    log         127.0.0.1 local2

    chroot      /var/lib/haproxy
    pidfile     /var/run/haproxy.pid
    maxconn     4000
    user        haproxy
    group       haproxy
    daemon

    stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats

defaults
    mode                    http
    log                     global
    option                  httplog
    option                  dontlognull
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          1m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

frontend http
    bind :80
    bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/certs/haproxy.pem
    use_backend apps.ocp.example.com
    default_backend apps.ocp.example.com

backend apps.ocp.example.com
    server 10.0.0.50 10.0.0.50:443 ssl check inter 1000 verify none
```

Comment: Also, another troubleshooting step I took to verify that haproxy is properly configured is I installed apache on the internal vm (IP 10.0.0.101), changed the haproxy backend to use it instead of the openshift *.apps server:    


        `server internal 10.0.0.101:443 ssl check inter 1000 verify none`    


And this worked properly.  So it has to be something specific to pointing the backend to the *.aps VIP.

Comment: Ok, dyslexia mistake, I swapped the apps and api addresses.  However, fixing that now gives me:

Application is not available
The application is currently not serving requests at this endpoint. It may not have been started or is still starting.